# How to run celery-beat task under decorator?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have "locker" decorator:

```
def lock_task(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if redis.set(func.__name__, 'lock', nx=True):
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                redis.delete(func.__name__)
            return result or True
        else:
            return 'Skipped'
    return wrapper
```

Also I have celery-task with my decorator:

```
@celery_app.task
@lock_task
def test():
    call_command('test')
```

And I have my celery-beat settings:

```
celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'test': {
        'task': 'project.celery.test',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1')
    }
}
```

After starting I got KeyError Received unregistered task of type 'project.celery.test'.

How to call this construct correct?

Comment: I added an answer which I updated just now. Could you check if the usage of `functools.wraps()` would work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `wrapper` function would be the one registered to celery instead of the actual `test` function. You can verify it if you see this logs when you start the celery worker:

```
$ celery --app=tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
...
[tasks]
  . project.celery.wrapper
```

To register the name of the actual task, use [functools.wraps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) which as documented:

> Without the use of this decorator factory, the name of the example function would have been 'wrapper'

```
from functools import wraps

def lock_task(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

If the error persists, make sure that you have configured correctly either:

- Celery [imports](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-imports) e.g. `celery_app.conf.update(imports=['project.celery'])` or `celery_app.conf.imports = ['project.celery']`
- Or Celery [include](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery-application-objects) ([example](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/next-steps.html#proj-celery-py)) e.g. `celery_app = Celery(..., include=['project.celery'])`

To verify, you should see your task named `project.celery.test` when you start the celery worker (to emphasize, the **worker**, not the **scheduler**):

```
$ celery --app=tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
...
[tasks]
  . project.celery.test
```

- See the last line. It should be visible if you invoked the worker with the flag `--loglevel=INFO`. If you don't see the task `test` in there or see the `wrapper` instead, then the above steps might help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding the name to decorator like

```
@celery_app.task(name='TASKNAME')
@lock_task
def test():
    call_command('test')
```

and then set this name to scheduler:

```
celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'test': {
        'task': 'TASKNAME',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1')
    }
}
```

It works for me.